Homodyne feedback equation: Stratnovich form to Ito form
I am trying to understand the paper of  equation 7 of Phys. Rev. Lett Vol 70, 548 (1993), Quantum theory of optical feedback via homodyne detection by H.M. Wiseman & G.J. Milburn.
(You can also find the paper in this website )
I want to understand equation 7 out of equation 6



The equation 6 of the paper is given by
\begin{align}
&\dot{\rho}_{c}^{(S)} = [ L - \frac{1}{2} \eta H^2 + \langle a + a^{\dagger} \rangle_c (t) K + \sqrt{\eta} \xi(t) ( H + \eta^{-1} K)] \rho_c 
\end{align}
and the equation 7 of the paper is given by
\begin{align}
\dot{\rho}_{c}^{(I)} = L \rho_c + K(a \rho_c + \rho_c a^{\dagger}) + \frac{1}{2 \eta} K^2 \rho_c + \sqrt{\eta} \xi(t) ( H + \eta^{-1} K) \rho_c
\end{align}
(which states that converting the equation 6 to Ito form gives this result)


In the paper the author states changing Stratonvich equation to Ito's form, the form of expectation vale of $a+a^{\dagger}$ changes to $a \rho + \rho a^{\dagger}$.  How this is possible?
I have no idea the expectation value of equation 6 disappear in equation 7.
What I know about Stratnovich form to Ito is following :
For given Stratnovich form $dX = A dt + B dW$, its Ito form is given by $dX = A dt + B dW + \frac{1}{2}B \partial B dt$
In this sense I understand the term $K^2$ comes due to this but having problem understanding expectation values to just operators.

Please don't use images/screenshots for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage using MathJax.

You'll find a comprehensive reference to Mathjax here.
